# Why do I need to give the hostname in netty socketio and how to handle socketio in docker?

Tags: socket.io, docker, netty

I am using netty-socketio for some project. I set up a server like so:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setHostname("localhost");
config.setPort(8080);

SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
server.start();
```

I have only few knowledge on all this and I was wondering why do I need to set the hostname here? Wouldn't it be enough to just give the port to listen?

Also, how do I handle this in Docker: I have the IP of my server, and the virtual IP of the container, which one should I give?

What if I have another server running in a different container (but on the same machine) and I want the two to communicate, how can I handle all those IP to achieve this? And will the communication be as efficient as if it was all on localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/blob/master/src/main/java/com/corundumstudio/socketio/Configuration.java#L164) setting hostname can be easily omitted. Basically this is just an interface that will socketio be bound into. So yes, you can specify only the port to listen - in this scenario it will listen on 0.0.0.0.

When it comes to docker you may not specify the hostname but configure port exposing. E.g. container will listen on 0.0.0.0:8888 which will be exposed to :8889 - see [port exposing](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/).

All the containers will be running with their unique IP assigned. If you want them to communicate to just need to set different ports to be bound to.